# Trigger a project based on multiple triggers

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I want to execute a project on a Friday every week at 1:00PM , If the build was not run any time in that particular week.

Could any help me in writting trigger for a Cruise Control Project.

Answer (score 1):

Use interval trigger that is set to run every week at 1:00pm and conditional block to check if last build time ran during that week, like this:

```
<conditional>
  <conditions>
    <lastBuildTimeCondition>
       <time unit="hours">168</time>
    </lastBuildTimeCondition>
   </conditions>
   <tasks>
     <msbuild />
   </tasks>
  <elseTasks>
    <!-- Something else, maybe comment task -->
  </elseTasks>
</conditional>
```